# I need to know how put my nav bar in the right up part on my web project

Tags: html, css

i want locate the nav bar in the right up part of the web, but i need that that will to be alined to the logo brand too

I'm a little bit new in code, because i've a better graphic design focus

```
figure {
width: 15%;
height: 25%;
margin: 3.5%;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

#navbar{
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  margin: 4%;
  position: top;
}

.prog, .BS, .Ho {
  margin: 3%;
}
```

Comment: Try adding some images/representations of what your code is currently displaying and what you expect it to display. It really helps! In this case, the positioning depends a little bit on how you structured your html, so we can identify which elements you're using and how your code hierarchy works.

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/bkdigital/pen/abbbVvo - Something like this?

```
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

https://flexboxfroggy.com/ - This fun game will help you learn flexbox.